# Visual C#: Not Building With Correct Runtime

Tags: .net, c, build, build-process, net-reactor

I am developing an application that has been running using the .Net Runtime v2.0. Because some of the features that are used in the application do not work on Windows 10, I am forced to update the runtime to v3.5. This isn't a big deal and doesn't change anything code-wise, but I am having issues actually going about changing it to 3.5 Framework.

I am able to set the target framework to 3.5 in the project properties without an issue. I am also able to build the project without any issues. There is never a single error thrown. Also, the project is obfuscated using the .Net Reactor version 3.9.8.

The problem occurs when I go and inspect the .dll or .exe file that is generated after building the release version. When I open it with .Net Reactor it shows that the runtime is v2.0. I have attached a picture of this.

Another thing to note is that the project does depend on a few other .dlls. In the picture I have included I have highlighted 3 dependencies in red. Those dependencies are other projects that I have developed and they are currently using runtime v2.0 as well. I have tried to update them to v3.5 but the same problem occurs. The dependencies highlighted in blue all show that the runtime version is v2.0 too.

Any help and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Project Properties]

[image: .Net Reactor]

Comment: That is correct, not counting the .NET 1.x versions there are only two runtime versions.  2.0.50727 used by framework versions 2.0 through 3.5 and 4.0.30319 used by framework version 4.0 and up.  Feature, not a bug.  Get ahead by not displaying it, it just isn't very helpful.

Comment: So @HansPassant you're saying that it is building in the correct runtime because the runtime version 2.0 is used for frameworks 2.0-3.5?

Comment: Well, 2.0.50727.  It is the version number of the CLR and the jitter.  The runtime version.  Framework versions get incremented when it acquires new assemblies.  Like the WPF assemblies in 3.0 and System.Core in 3.5

Comment: Oh OK I understand. For some reason I thought that the runtime version reflected the framework version. Thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx, note the "CLR Version" column. Also see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karinm/2008/11/10/whats-the-difference-between-clr-and-net-framework/